# is it possible to mount host file to docker container only if it exists?

Tags: docker

When mounting a host file as a volume, is there a way to prevent docker from creating a host directory if the file does not exist?

For example:

```
docker run --mount=type=bind,src=$HOME/.Xauthority,dst=/root/.Xauthority ..
```

actually creates a .Xauthority directory at the home directory on the host.

.Xauthority has only ssh server, but I want to use the same docker command on a computer that is not an ssh server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a job for a shell script.

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.Xauthority" ]; then
  docker run --mount=type=bind,src=$HOME/.Xauthority,dst=/root/.Xauthority ..
else
  docker run ..
fi
```